# How to remove [object Object] in mat-form-field Angular Meterial

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Meterial Angular FormField. How do I remove defaulve in my form:

[image]

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Ngày nhận</mat-label>
            <input matInput placeholder="Ngày nhận"
                   [formControl]="ngayNhanFormControl"
                   required
            >
            <mat-error *ngIf="( ngayNhanFormControl.errors?.required)"></mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
```

And this is my code:

```
this.ngayNhanFormControl = new FormControl({value: ''}, [Validators.required]);
...

this.theoDoiPhoiGCNFormGroup = new FormGroup({
      NgayNhan: this.ngayNhanFormControl,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because you are initializing your `FormControl` with an object `{value: ''}`. Change your code to this:

```
this.ngayNhanFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
```